# Problem of interacting with Smart Contract via HTML and JavaScript application

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-invocation, testrpc, javascript

I followed and tested "[Creating a Web UI for our Smart Contract](https://coursetro.com/courses/20/Developing-Ethereum-Smart-Contracts-for-Beginners/lessons/3)" tutorial and it works well.

However, when I do exactly what I did in the above tutorial for [**THIS SMART CONTRACT**](https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard), I do not see the output in its HTML page. (You can find all of this contract files [HERE](https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard))

Gere is what I do step by step :

1. create a new file in remix and copy smart contract code from [here](https://gist.github.com/tomconte/ca2e2927d72b472c5ee24f3db71a0987).
2. open a cmd window.
3. type "testrpc", then press "Enter".
4. from "Environment" menue, select "Web3 provider".
5. click on "Deploy" button. See screen shot please.

[image]

6. copy "account" and "contract address" and replace them with ones are written in `viz.js` file. I mean `var account` and `var contractAddress` You can see this file content [here](https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard/blob/master/viz.js).
7. then I open index.html file to invoke functions.

**However, I do not see any output or result.** Please see screen shot below.

[image]

What is my mistake to interact with this contract ? The problem is using **testRPC** ?

Comment: open the transaction info and check 'decoded output'. I can see it properly

Comment: @mirg Thanks. Did you do steps as I mentioned in my question ? honestly I did not understand how to open "transaction info" ? Do you see the output via index.html file ? I uploaded what I can see after opening index.html file and clicking on "sell" and "buy" buttons. If I have to do some additional steps that I mentioned in my question (steps 1 to 7), please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: just click on the transaction line 'from: ... to: ...'. I don't see the output via your 'index.html' (I just tested in remix)

Comment: @mirg I can see output in remix. However, my lain purpose is to interaction with this contract via index.html file that has been generated by author of this contract. You can see all of related files here : [link](https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard)

Comment: look at the error console in your browser f12

Comment: @Badr Bellaj Thanks I saw 4 errors, but do not know how to fix them. i am new in javascript..

Comment: add the error's screenshot in your post

Comment: @Badr Bellaj I could fix 3 errors. one error remained. I added screen shot to my question. I do not know how to add this file to my project. Thanks.